# Prevent unmounted DVD remounting after resume

Tags: mount, suspend, dvd

When I have a dvd in my laptop, I like to unmount it if I am not using it.  Otherwise, the laptop will keep the dvd spun up for long stretches of time, which is annoying.

Whenever I open my laptop, and it resumes from suspend, it remounts the DVD, and automatically starts up parole player, autostarting the DVD.  This takes up lots of time while all this is starting up.  Is there a way to get ubuntu to respect my unmount decision across resumes?